# Reduce file size of an image

Tags: android, arrays, image, compression, byte

I have taken a picture with the android camera. The result is an byte array. I save it by writing it on the sdcard (FileOutputStream). The result is an image with a filesize of nearly 3mb. I would like to reduce this filesize, so compress the image.

It would be nice if it is possible to reduce the filesize before i would write the byte array to the output stream. Is that possible or do I have to save it first?

Comment: Which part of the code? This is the code to save the picture:   FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                  try{
                      outStream = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/Image.jpg");
                      outStream.write(data);
                      outStream.close();...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I usually resize the image which reduces the size of it

```
Bitmap bitmap = resizeBitMapImage1(exsistingFileName, 800, 600);
```

You can also compress an image with this code

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
_bitmapScaled.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);

//you can create a new file name "test.jpg" in sdcard folder.
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator + "test.jpg")
f.createNewFile();
//write the bytes in file
FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());

// remember close de FileOutput
fo.close();
```

Re-sizing Code

```
public static Bitmap resizeBitMapImage1(String filePath, int targetWidth, int targetHeight) {
    Bitmap bitMapImage = null;
    try {
        Options options = new Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
        double sampleSize = 0;
        Boolean scaleByHeight = Math.abs(options.outHeight - targetHeight) >= Math.abs(options.outWidth
                - targetWidth);
        if (options.outHeight * options.outWidth * 2 >= 1638) {
            sampleSize = scaleByHeight ? options.outHeight / targetHeight : options.outWidth / targetWidth;
            sampleSize = (int) Math.pow(2d, Math.floor(Math.log(sampleSize) / Math.log(2d)));
        }
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inTempStorage = new byte[128];
        while (true) {
            try {
                options.inSampleSize = (int) sampleSize;
                bitMapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
                break;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                try {
                    sampleSize = sampleSize * 2;
                } catch (Exception ex1) {

                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
    return bitMapImage;
}
```

Comment: I know this way of compression. But how do i get the Bitmap as the result of the byte array?

Comment: stream.toByteArray() returns a byte array. But i have a byte array. So i need to get the BitMap of the byte array. Or did i misunderstand you?

Comment: @JavaForAndroid I guess I'm not getting you. What exactly do you need . Do you want to convert the `ByteArray()` to Image?? And save it??\

Comment: I have an image. This is a byte array. I would like to reduce the image size, so i have to convert the byte array to a bitmap. Then i would compress the bitmap and save the image.

Comment: Solved it with your help. I did this:  Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                     ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                     bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);