# How to reduce image programmatically in Android?

Tags: android

I am programmatically taking screenshot of the screen in my android app using the following code. It is working fine. The problem I see is, it is taking screenshot of the entire layout and viewing. When I execute this in Tablet, it is taking tablet the bigger size screen, so i have a problem in viewing. Can I reduce this image size? For example: If it is taking screenshot of the view, which is 1920 x 1200, Can I reduce this image further programmatically to 1200 * 650, like that?

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(Context context, View v) {
        DisplayMetrics dm = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

        v.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(dm.widthPixels, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(dm.heightPixels, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));

        v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());

        Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getMeasuredWidth(),
                v.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);

        v.draw(canvas);
        return returnedBitmap;
    }
```

Comment: [Check if this helps](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17260111/1777090)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Bitmap resizedImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(old_bitmap,desiredimageWidth,desiredimageHeight, true);
```