# Android Does converting image to byte array result in same data size

Tags: java, android, arrays, image

I have converted image to byte array 
my image size is 57 kb and after converting my byte array resulted in 200kb length

is my code correct or wrong 
if so can anyone share the code to result same size

```
 ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
    int size = imageInByte.length;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Byte Array length : " + size,  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: share the code that you have tried

Comment: share the code first where you get error.

Comment: @GautamChibde can u suggest any other method or code

Comment: @HemantParmar can u suggest any other method or code

Comment: @CheralaVivek have look [Reduce bitmap image by byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17260111/5110595)